# On Imported content I am getting the error Text format field is required

Tags: 8, nodes, forms, importing-exporting

I imported some content to a content type on a csv which imported fine but when I went to edit and same the content I get the error Text format field is required. Is there any known way to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add default value for text format when you migrate content. Example body field

```
'body/format':
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: basic_html
'body/value': body
```

After update config migration you need update migration with command

```
drush mim MIGRATATION_ID --update
```